# Set time picker on time base

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to set timepicker that way that it should be greater then current time and less the time set.
for Ex:
It should be greater than the current time and less than 5 pm.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [MaterialTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) library. It has methods for choosing selectable days, times etc..